# Why nginx-based docker image refuses connection in VSCode devcontainer

Tags: docker, nginx, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, vscode-devcontainer

Consider following setup:

`devcontainer.json`

```json
{
  "name": "Deputy devcontainer",
  "dockerComposeFile": "docker-compose.yml",
  "service": "go-development",
  "settings": {
    "go.toolsManagement.checkForUpdates": "local",
    "go.useLanguageServer": true,
    "go.gopath": "/go"
  },
  "extensions": [
    "golang.Go",
    "gitlab.gitlab-workflow",
    "GitHub.copilot",
    "eamodio.gitlens",
    "zxh404.vscode-proto3",
    "bungcip.better-toml"
  ],
  "workspaceFolder": "/workspace",
  "remoteUser": "vscode"
}
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  go-development:
    image: my-custom-docker-repository/go-development:latest
    command: /bin/sh -c "while sleep 1000; do :; done"
    volumes:
      - ..:/workspace:cached
      - ./deputy-cli-configuration.toml:/home/vscode/.deputy/configuration.toml
    user: vscode

  deputy-package-server:
    image: my-custom-docker-repository/deputy-package-server:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./deputy-packages:/var/opt/deputy/deputy-package-server/package
      - ./deputy-repository:/var/opt/deputy/deputy-package-server/repository
    environment:
      - RUST_LOG=debug

  index-repository:
    image: my-custom-docker-repository/deputy-repository-server
    volumes:
      - ./deputy-repository/.git:/srv/git/index.git
    ports:
      - "8082:80"
```

`Dockerfile` for `index-repository`:

```
FROM teamfruit/nginx-fcgiwrap

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install git-core fcgiwrap -y
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

`nginx.conf` in `index-repository`:

```
server {
    listen       80;

    location ~ /git(/.*) {
        client_max_body_size            0;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME     /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend;
        include       fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_param   GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL   "";
        fastcgi_param   GIT_PROJECT_ROOT    /srv/git;
        fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO           $1;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
    }
}
```

`Dockerfile` for `go-development`:

```
FROM vscode/devcontainers/go

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install protobuf-compiler make debhelper dpkg-dev -y
RUN go install google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc@v1.2
RUN go install google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go@v1.28
RUN chmod 777 -R /go/pkg
```

When running the `vscode-devcontainer`, it is impossible to `git clone http://index-repository/git/index.git`, this fails with `connection refused`.

[image: connection-refused-image]

However, when I try to clone either directly in the `index-repository` or host machine, the commands succeeds. Also connecting to `deputy-package-server` (a simple Rust web-server) works without any issues.

[image: successful-clone-inside-docker-machine]

I can also see from the `tcpdump` that the request actually reaches the `nginx-container`:

[image]

I also used `dig` to verify that `dns` is not a problem.

[image]

As of right now I am really puzzled as to why the connection keeps getting refused. I am suspecting that the issue may lie somewhere in the `nginx` configuration, but cannot tell where. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mapping the port `"8082:80"`, so you should access the `index-repository` container by `http://localhost:8082` isntead of `http://index-repository:8082`.

If you want to access the repositroy server container by the domain name `index-repository`, you should expose the port 80 of the repositroy server container (the hostname would be defaulted in the docker network as same as the service id, eg. `index-repository`).

Then your dev container can access it as `http://index-repository:80`

Comment: Exactly, I erroneously presumed that ´ports´ will open docker ports for other containers on the docker network, but in reality, it maps those ports to the host machine. That is why I was getting `Connection refused` there just was not anything listening on `http://index-repository:8082`.